# Checking for duplicate numbers in a 2D matrix and containing the data into two variables

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array, duplicates

I am trying to check 2D matrix array for the correct numbers and extras on each row and then printing them out only once per correct number/extra.

I.e. if 34 is twice in jackpot and once in the matrix row it should only record it once.

Correct numbers are first 7 numbers of jackpot array and the extras are the last 3 numbers.

Can anyone explain why the Row 2's 1 extra is being eliminated from my current output?

I am guessing it is because the correct number 34 is already recorded in previous[] and this is then compared to the extra 34 and thus extra is substracted by 1.

How would one go about fixing this, should I make another array that stores the previous extras or something?

The correct output:

```
Row 1 has 0 correct and 0 extras!
Row 2. has 1 correct and 1 extras!
Row 3. has 3 correct and 0 extras!
Row 4. had 1 correct and 1 extras!
Row 5. has 1 correct and 0 extras!
```

My current output:

```
Row 1. has 0 correct and 0 extras! 
Row 2. has 1 correct and 0 extras! 
Row 3. has 3 correct and 0 extras!
Row 4. has 1 correct and 1 extras!
Row 5. has 1 correct and 0 extras!
```

```
for (int z = 0; z < NUM_PER_ROW; z++) 
{
    if (previous[z] == jackpot[k] && k <= 6) 
    {
        correct -=1;
        break;
    }
    else if (previous[z] == jackpot[k] && k > 6) 
    {
        extra -=1;
        break;
    }
}
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX_ROWS 5
#define NUM_PER_ROW 7
#define MAX_NUM 40

int doStuff();

int doStuff() 
{
    int matrix[MAX_ROWS][NUM_PER_ROW] = { 
        { 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7}, 
        {30, 38,  6, 34,  4, 39, 30},
        { 9, 37, 32, 27,  9, 39, 17}, 
        { 8, 26,  6, 31, 28, 29, 16}, 
        {33, 21, 19,  7,  9, 19, 30} };
    int jackpot[NUM_PER_ROW + 3] = 
        {20, 37, 22,  9, 34, 28, 34, 24, 26, 29};
    int num = 0, i, j, cnt = 0, temp = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < MAX_ROWS; i++) 
    {
        int correct = 0;
        int extra = 0;

        for(j = 0; j < NUM_PER_ROW; j++)
        {
            int previous[7] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

            for (int k = 0; k < NUM_PER_ROW + 3; k++) 
            {
                if (matrix[i][j] == jackpot[k]) 
                {
                    for (int z = 0; z < NUM_PER_ROW; z++) 
                    {
                        if (previous[z] == jackpot[k] && k <= 6) 
                        {
                            correct -= 1;
                            break;
                        }
                        else if (previous[z] == jackpot[k] && k > 6) 
                        {
                            extra -=1;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (k <= 6) 
                    {                       
                        correct += 1;
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        extra += 1;

                    }

                    previous[j] = jackpot[k];
                }
            }
        }

        printf("Row %d. has %d correct and %d extras! \n", i + 1, correct, extra);
    }

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int num;
    srand(time(NULL));

    doStuff(num);

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Given that repeat numbers in the matrix should only count once, it's probably easier to iterate over `jackpot` in the outer loop. Once you see a match in the inner loop over `matrix` you can just break out of it.

Comment: I suggest using an array of length `NUM_PER_ROW + 3` of flags marking which elements in the jackpot array are duplicates that should be skipped. You only need to fill that out once before the main loop. Then the main loop will only need to be 3 levels deep instead of 4. The `k` loop can check the array of flags to see if the current element  of the jackpot is a duplicate and ignore it if so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using an array to mark the duplicates in `jackpot[]`:

```
    char jp_dupe[NUM_PER_ROW + 3];

    for (i = 0; i < NUM_PER_ROW + 3; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < i && jackpot[i] != jackpot[j]; j++)
            ;
        jp_dupe[i] = (i != j); /* 0 if first occurrence, 1 if a duplicate */
    }
```

Then there is no need for the `previous[]` array or the `z` loop, and the `k` loop can be simplified:

```
            for (int k = 0; k < NUM_PER_ROW + 3; k++) 
            {
                if (!jp_dupe[k] && matrix[i][j] == jackpot[k]) 
                {
                    if (k < NUM_PER_ROW) 
                    {                       
                        correct += 1;
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        extra += 1;
                    }
                }
            }
```

I took the liberty of replacing the `<= 6` test to avoid the magic number.  The magic number `3` could also be replaced with a macro.

Comment: This was a very insightful answer! I did manage to get it working by doing another array for the extras, but this uses much less resources and is a much better implementation on all fronts! Thank you so much!